# PHP cookie use, help?

Tags: php, session, cookies

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token'])){
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');}

$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

setcookie('oauth_token', $access_token['oauth_token'], time()+60*60*24*30);
setcookie('oauth_token_secret', $access_token['oauth_token_secret'], time()+60*60*24*30);
}
//else use the cookies
else{
$oauth_token = $_COOKIE['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
}
```

Here is the snippet of code I am using, basically I want to store a long term cookie for the user so they don't have to login to Twitter and go through the long process of authorizing my web app every time they connect. So I am attempting to use cookies with this library ([twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/)) for some reason the page won't load with this section of code, if I was to take out the if else and just leave the $_SESSION part in the code works without a hitch.

I'm quite confused as I've checked and the cookies are successfully getting stored, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your 'check' for the cookie is incorrect (not code wise, but logic wise), let me remove all the code exect for the `if`-`else`-statement:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token'])){
    // Using $_SESSION
}
// else use the cookie
else {
    // Using $_COOKIE
}
```

Your logic says *'if the cookie exists use sessions, else use the cookie'* and I think you meant to say *'if the cookie does **not** exist use sessions, else use the cookie'*. You have to invert your check in the first `if`-statement.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token'])) {
    // Use cookie here
}
```

---

**Update** I've re-read the section you posted over and over again and, as you say your script does not have any output with that piece of code, the only thing I can come up with is that your application crashes on `new TwitterOAuth(...);`. Can you try to run your code without those two lines (temporarily remove them both and see if you have a page output).

---

**Update #2** I've noticed you said that your code-'snippit' does work, but the combined code does not. You use `header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');` if the session is not set, if you replace that by `echo "error";`, do you get that in the browser window. *Note* This is very simplistic debugging as I have little knowledge of what goes on on your system, but it is proven to be effective in times. You can also choose to use the echo-`flush()` combo, which will force output to the browser everytime you pass a certain line (you can then check how far your code is executing).

Comment: Yeah I changed it, although I took note from the isset I did invert the check. It's still failing to execute though.

Comment: Updated my answer, could you please check if the `TwitterOAuth()` is your problem?

Comment: Right, I just tried some changes. I've pastebin'd them so they are a bit easier to see than in a comment. http://pastebin.com/r9DtcUSW - I would fully understand if you don't have the time to read through that. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Updated my answer, but I'm still not sure what the problem is, I can't see anything wrong with your code...

Comment: Thanks, I actually fixed it a few hours after posting my reply. For some reason changing the layout of the if made it work. I'm not completely sure why, I think it could have been a combination of my drowsiness and the fact I didn't flush my cookies and it was using an invalid session. Thanks for your help though! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not empty or do not return empty even if they are not set, you should try

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token'])) {
```

More info on
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Tried both, still fails to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token'])){
```

Note the exclamation mark ;) Meaning if NOT (is)set.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what parts of code that the logic don't go into?

Comment: If you want, I have elaborated more in a larger paste found here; http://pastebin.com/r9DtcUSW